# C#: Task cancellation not working (CancellationTokenSource)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, task-parallel-library

I have some long running code that I would like to run as a `Task` and cancel when needed using `CancellationTokenSource` but cancellation doesn't seem to work as my task keeps running when `tokenSource.Cancel()` is called (no exception thrown).

Probably missing something obvious?

Cut down example below:

```
bool init = false;

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
    Task task = new Task(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Operation is going to be cancelled");
                throw new Exception("Task cancelled");
            }
            else
            {
                // do some work
            }
        }
    }, token);

    if (init)
    {
        tokenSource.Cancel();
        button1.Text = "Start again";
        init = false;
    } else
    {
        try
        {
            task.Start();
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        button1.Text = "Cancel";
        init = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating a new `Task` on every `Button1_Click`. Try moving the `task` and `tokenSource` variables to the outer scope, and initialize them once.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Good point, although no change in behaviour when I moved `Task task` out of button click handler. Still not seeing any exceptions thrown.

Comment: You have to move the token source as well

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Yup, that did the trick (as per the accepted answer below). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main issue in your code is that you don't store a `tokenSource`. Second `Button1_Click` invocation cancels different token than you pass to task during first call.

Second issue is that you create over and over again new task, but your logic suggest that you want one task which should be created on first click and terminated during second click.

Comment: Bingo, moving the `Task`, `CancellationTokenSource` and the `CancellationToken` out of the button click handler fixed the issue. Thanks!